# How to create a table with 2 cell left and 3 cell right?

Tags: html, html-table

How to create a table with 2 cells left and 3 cells right in HTML ?
Like this :

[image: Table]

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`rowspan`](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_30.html)

Comment: What do you mean by cells left and right? If you want to make the first two left cells smaller then the last three, use colspan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to creat this you need to use 3 table like this

```
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:solid 1px #333;">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%" style="border-right:solid 1px #333;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom:solid 1px #333;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom:solid 1px #333;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom:solid 1px #333;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/UHu7E/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the table have 6 rows.
The left one will have 2 cells with 3 rows.
The right one will have 3 cells with 2 rows.

e.g.`th rowspan="2"`

Answer (score 0):

you can create a usual table with 5 cells, but place it in a 
 way that visually will be wil 2 cell on the LEFT of your landmark, and 3 cell on the RIGHT of your landmark :)

---

**EDIT:**
(improved the answer, after author has provided more details, by attaaching the picture)

Create a table with 6 rows and 2 columns. After that use RowSpan and it's solved. 
(see attached image)

[image]